# Unable to add time to TimeField in django model [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: django, django-models, graphql

I have a django model like this...

```
class ConversionResults(models.Model):
conversion_results_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
conversion_rate_a = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
clicks_a = models.IntegerField()
conversion_rate_b = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
clicks_b = models.IntegerField()
week = models.IntegerField()
date = models.DateField()
time = models.TimeField()

objects = models.Manager()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'conversion_results'

def __int__(self):
    return self. conversion_results_id
```

When I try to add data to the model, like below

```
ConversionResults(
                conversion_rate_a=conversion_rate_today_a,
                conversion_rate_b=conversion_rate_today_b,
                clicks_a=ctc_today_a,
                clicks_b=ctc_today_b,
                week=week,
                date=today_date,
                time=datetime.datetime.today().time()   # the error is here
            ).save()
```

I am getting error with the time field as shown below

```
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

I don't get how this is even related to decimal, the model contains a TimeField. Any help will be appreciated

Below is the full Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 487, in _resolve_from_executor
    executor(resolve, reject)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 754, in executor
    return resolve(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphql/execution/middleware.py", line 75, in make_it_promise
    return next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shashank/project/server/data_distribution/query.py", line 416, in resolve_daily_updates
    time=datetime.datetime.today().time()  # the error is here 
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1331, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1275, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1275, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1274, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1215, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1563, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py", line 516, in adapt_decimalfield_value
    return utils.format_number(value, max_digits, decimal_places)
  File "/home/shashank/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 238, in format_number
    value = value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(1).scaleb(-decimal_places), context=context)
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

Comment: What DB backend are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I am using MySQL

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: Can you inspect/log `conversion_rate_today_a` and `conversion_rate_today_b`? The error is almost certainly in these values

Comment: `56.56108597285068
115.38461538461537
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>`    These are the values and data types of them, they seem correct

Comment: Neither of those values are decimals, try converting them to decimals before passing them to your model? `conversion_rate_a=Decimal(conversion_rate_today_a)`

Comment: `56.56
115.38
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>` I did that and I got the same error again, next I rounded it off to 2 decimal placed as in the database the type said `decimal(4,2)` and it's the same error all over again.

Comment: @ShashankAC the value `115.38` does not fit within `decimal(4,2)`. I had the same problem and changing `max_digits` on model fixed it.